# Работа с SortedDictionary - C#

Tags: c#

```
 SortedDictionary<int, int> dic = new SortedDictionary<int,int>();
```

Есть число в каждой строчке, + оно добавляется, - нужно убрать

```
 +5
 +7
 +5
 +4
 +8
 +8
 -8
 ...
```

Как мне загнать все через цикл в sortedictionary и вывести на консоль через цикл, обратиться к элементу, заменить его, как с ним работать?

Получить хочу число и его количество

```
dic = { 4, 1
        5, 2
        7, 1
        8, 2 }
```

Comment: Это не сайт, где за вас выполняют домашнюю работу. Покажите, код, который у вас уже есть. Что-то у вас ведь уже есть или же вы ничего не делали и хотите, чтобы ВСЁ сделали за вас?

Answer (score 2):

Добавляйте каждое число следующим образом, я обозначил приходящее число `x`:

```
int key = Math.Abs(x);
if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
    dic[key] = 0;
dic[key] += Math.Sign(x);
```

Math.Sign() вернёт +1 для положительного параметра и -1 для отрицательного, чем мы и воспользуемся.

Comment: и прям `dic[x]++;` работает? Здорово.

Comment: @Igor, а почему не должно-то?

Comment: Напишите развернутый ответ, как через цикл загонять, как выводить, как удалять, как заменять, как присваивать новое значение, неужели никто с srteddictionary не знаком?

Comment: @Андрей В Delphi не работало - инкремент прикладывался к временной переменной возвращаемой гетером.

Comment: @Igor, в шарпе работает так как вы этого ожидаете, такого подвоха, к счастью, нету

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, а вы не знакомы с циклами? С вводом/выводом на консоль? Или хотите чтоб я вам пару страниц из книжки или из MSDN в ответ скопировал? Работа с SortedDictionary ничем не отличается от работы с обычным словарем. Как проверить наличие ключа и как записать/заменить ключ и значение в ответе есть.

Comment: Я написал выше, что только с массивами работал, а потом написал, что хочу чтобы вы написали

Comment: Напишите развернутый ответ, как через цикл загонять, как выводить, как удалять, как заменять, как присваивать новое значение, неужели никто с srteddictionary не знаком?

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, я дополнил ответ под вашу задачу, в цикл уж пожалуйста сами оберните, если вы с массивами работали, то циклы должны знать

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов, а мы хотим видеть меньше вопросов оформленных в таком стиле(это я про откровенное неуважение к людям, которые бесплатно пытаются вам помочь).

Comment: Ещё один вариант: `int key = Math.Abs(x); dic.TryGetValue(key, out var val); dic[key] = val + Math.Sign(x);`. (Сэкономили одну строчку.)

Comment: @VladD, а разве можно гарантировать, что при false, val будет нулем, а не чем-нибудь еще? :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну вроде да, [см. раздел Комментарии](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx#Комментарии)